# Outlook 2010 add-in: how to go through all mail messages?

Tags: c#, email, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing a simple Outlook 2010 add-in in C# that would go through all the e-mail messages and would search for a certain text in each message's subject and body. The add-in scaffold (like the add-in that does integrate to Outlook, a custom ribbon with a bunch of buttons - stuff like that) is in place and working, but, rather unexpectedly, I don't seem to be able to figure out how to do the central part - go through the mail messages. Attempts to find working examples or tutorials didn't yield any results, there's plenty of "hello world" things, but nothing else...

I would very much appreciate a hint on how to go through the mail messages in an add-in.

Comment: This has already been answered numerous times before. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098485/how-to-loop-through-all-mailitems-of-certain-outlook-subfolders) for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the inbox folder and get the mail items from there:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = 
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.DefaultStore
    .GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

foreach (object item in inbox.Items)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mail = item as Outlook.MailItem;

    if (mail != null)
    {
        // use the mail item
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seen this kind of code around, but "System.Windows.Forms.Application does not contain a definition for Session"...

Comment: That is the wrong namespace. You should have `using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`;

Comment: This is not that `Application`. Remove WinForms namespace import from the top of your cs file, or if you need it, make an alias for it.

Comment: Ok, but now "The name 'Application' doesn't exist in the current context"... I'm clearly doing something wrong, but what? Here's what I have in the "using" section of the file in question:

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Comment: Then prefix it with `Globals.ThisAddIn.`. Updated the answer.